# How to extract text from html using XPATH

Tags: r, xpath

```
url <- "http://www.officedepot.com/a/browse/technology/N=5+9021/;jsessionid=00000a2ZDz-8D4MKY5wMPuithDX:17h4h7bfo"

library(RCurl)
library(XML)
html <- getURL(url[u])

trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
docs <- htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
data <-xpathApply(docs, "//*[not(self::script)]/text()",xmlValue)
data <- trim(gsub('\t|\n',' ',unlist(data)))
data <- data[data!='']
head(data)
```

Above code successfully extract all text from any url but along with text, I'm getting some **style tag data**

like, see below style tag

```
<style>
    .dat_wrapper {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .cke_widget_element .dat_wrapper {
      visibility: visible;
    }
```

And extracted text from this tag using XPATH expresseion I mentioned above, **see output of data[2]**

```
> data[2]
```

[1] ".dat_wrapper {visibility: hidden;}     .cke_widget_element .dat_wrapper {visibility: visible;}"

I do not want such data. Please anybody help me to overcome this.

Comment: So you want to skip only `<script>` and `<style>` tags? So wouldn't `"//*[not(self::script) and not(self::style)]/text()"` work?

Comment: @MrFlick I already tried with this but it changes the result. If you execute my code written in question, you will get all text along with some css. so I wanna remove such css and javascript keeping everything same.

Comment: Don't you want to change the result by removing the css? I don't understand what your desired output is. What else changes? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MrFlick I wanna read only text from any url.  I'm using `//*[not(self::script)]/text()` but this XATH expression gives text and scripting data in a vector. So I want only text and not scripting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to extract all the information in "Technologies" section with detailed description of each product?

If so, the solution would be straightforward, first parse the url's then extract the content. Now your code and inquiry doesn't make any sense.